# R - How to calculate with values by different minutes per hour within the same column

Tags: r, date, posixct

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I have a Dataset with Datetimes [posixct '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'] and Sensor measurements in [A] and [V].
The Datetime is one column and the different sensors are the other columns, with one column for each sensor.

I'd like to calculate a correction value with values within the column of each sensor. 
The correction value should be written into a new colum hourly.
Therefore I'd like to calculate the correction as following:

correction = |x - (0.5 * (y+z))|

x= value of sensor 1, if Minute =='00'

y= value of sensor 1, if Minute =='03'

z= value of sensor 1, if Minute =='06'

What I'd like to have is a function, which calculates the written formula for every hour, but only if a value for all three minutes ('00'&'03'&'06') in the hour is given and write out the correction value into a new column (Data$correction). 
I hope I could explain, what I'd like to do.

I tried several loops and apply and mapply functions, but there was always a problem with the date format, or the function.
This is, what seems to be the the best approach to me, though it doesn't work right now, but I hope there is a way to make it start working.
Also I think, that writing out vectors and merge them back with melt or merge might not be the best way. but right now I'm jst struggling and don't now how to solve the problem.

I really hope you can help me. Thanks so much.

```
Test_sub <- read.table(file= 'Test_sub.csv',
header=T, sep= ';', dec='.', stringsAsFactors= F)

sensor1_V_0 <- Test_sub[format(Test_sub$Datehour, format = '%M') ==           '00',]
sensor1_V_3 <- Test_sub[format(Test_sub$Datehour, format = '%M') == '03',]
sensor12_V_6 <- Test_sub[format(Test_sub$Datehour, format = '%M') == '06',]

test_sub2<- mapply(function(x, y, z) x-(0.5*(y+z)), sensor1_V_0$sensor1_V,     sensor1_V_3$sensor1_V, sensor1_V_6$sensor1_V)
```

Comment: Furthermore I'd like to load up the Dataset (.csv) but I can't find a way, how to do so. Maybe one could link the help, where this is explained. Thanks again!

Comment: you mean `read.csv()`?

Comment: Actually I meant I'd like to load up the dataset on stackpverflow.

Comment: It might be helpful to load up the data here. But I can't find the button to attach some data here.
I already know how to load the Data in R, but Thanks.

Comment: You can't load the data on Stack overflow. You can provide a sample of the data using `dput(head(data, 20))`.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by creating some fake data:

```
dill<-data.frame(time=seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 11:30"), as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 13:20"), by=180),val=runif(37,0,100))
```

Now we can do this:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)
dill<- dill %>% 
group_by(hour(time)) %>% # group by the hour -- note this assumes there's only one day in the data, you'll need to adjust this if there's more than one day
filter(any(minute(time)==3) & any(minute(time)==6) & any(minute(time)==0)) %>% # remove any hours in the data that don't have minutes 0, 3 and 6
mutate(correction=abs(val[minute(time)==0]-0.5*(val[minute(time)==3]+val[minute(time)==6]))) # calculate the correction
```

Comment: First of all. Thanks a lot for your answer.
I tried your code. But even, if I use the example dataframe 'dill' R would gve me the folowing error message Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "hour".
I can't see what's the problem with this

Comment: Sorry, my bad - forgot to include `require(lubridate)`. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your promt answer.
It's working right now. But i was wondering, if there's any possibility to write out the Data into a new colum of the same dataset, because I need the correction values later for following calculations with the whole dataset.

Unfortunalety a simple allocation doesn't work. I tried:
dill$correction <- dill %>%     and so on...

Comment: Later I'd like to merge back the subset to the originally dataframe dill to calculate with all the values. 
Because of this, my approach was, to write a 'for-loop' combinded with a 'if-else' loop, which should write out the correction value into a new colum 'correction, because I have to calculate sevaral values "by hour" later. 
Therefore I could  simply adapt the loop, every time I have to calculate a new value

Comment: So this was the reason, why I preferred a loop. Do you have an idea, how to do  this with a loop, because later for example I'd like to calculate the difference between the value of minute '03' and the 'correction value'.

Comment: Furthermore I have to select by hour and date, because there are serveral days of observation, which are in the dataset.

Comment: The mutate call generates a full copy of the dataframe plus the additional column(s). All you need to do is assign the whole pipe block back to the initial dataframe name (see the revised example above).

Comment: None of what you described needs a for loop. Use the group_by function instead. You might want to delve more deeply into the dplyr package to understand how it works and how it can help you achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried what you suggested, but I have data over a period of time. Because of this I extended the function as following. But for any reason, it doesn't work. I don't get an error message, though nothing happens.
Can you see a mistake in my code?

Comment: `TestSub$Datehour <- as.POSIXct(TestSub$Datehour, format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')`
`TestSub %>%`
`group_by(date(Datehour), hour(Datehour)) %>% ` 
`filter(any(minute(Datehour)==3) & any(minute(Datehour)==6) & any(minute(Datehour)==0)) %>% `
`mutate(correction=abs(sensor1_V[minute(Datehour)==0]-0.5*(sensor1_V[minute(Datehour)==3]+sensor1_V[minute(Datehour)==6])))`

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data to your question?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I went on vacation, before I could read this.

Comment: Example for the data would be:

Answer (score 0):

An example of the data would be:

```
y <- seq(from= 0.1, to= 0.5, by= 0.1)
min <- as.POSIXct('2018-09-25 09:00:00')
max <- as.POSIXct('2018-09-26 17:45:00')
SEQ <- data.frame(Datehour = seq.POSIXt(min,max, by = 60*03))
str(SEQ)
SEQ <- data.frame(SEQ[format(SEQ, format = '%M') == '00' | 
                                format(SEQ, format = '%M') == '03' |
                                format(SEQ, format = '%M') == '06' |
                                format(SEQ, format = '%M') == '15' |
                            format(SEQ, format = '%M') == '30' |
                            format(SEQ, format = '%M') == '45' ,])

data <- data.frame(Datehour=SEQ, y = 0.1, z= 0.3)
```